# Documenting unfinished development work - Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, javac, annotation-processing, java-5

Using Javadoc, to document objects of type(`workWithAnnot`,`Method`,`Constructor`,`Annotation`,`Package`) as *unfinished* in development, below is the code,

```
src
   package1
      package-info.java
      Unfinished.java
   test
      package-info.java
      workWithAnnot.java
```

---

## package1/package-info.java

```
@Unfinished("Package scope")
package package1;
```

---

## package1/Unfinished.java

```
package package1;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Unfinished("Just articleware")
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR,
            ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.PACKAGE})
@Inherited
public @interface Unfinished {
    public enum Priority {LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH}
    String value();
    String[] owners() default "";
    Priority priority() default Priority.MEDIUM;
}
```

---

## test/workWithAnnot.java

```
package test;
import package1.Unfinished;
import package1.Unfinished.Priority;

@Unfinished(
        value = "Class Scope",
        priority = Priority.LOW
        )
public class workWithAnnot {

    @Unfinished(owners = "xyz", value="Method scope")
    public void foo() {

    }

    @Unfinished(owners = "Sham", value="Method scope")
    public void bar() {

    }
}
```

---

## test/package-info.java

```
@Unfinished("Package scope")
package test;

import package1.Unfinished;
```

---

Javadoc displays objects of  `Package` type as unfinished in Java syntax **but not** as documentation(in plain english):

> @Unfinished(value="Package scope")
>
> Package test

Javadoc displays objects of  `workWithAnnot` type as unfinished in Java syntax but not as  documentation:

> @Unfinished(value="Class Scope",
>                   priority=LOW)
>
> public class workWithAnnot extends java.lang.Object

Javadoc displays objects of  `Method` type as unfinished in Java syntax but not as documentation:

> foo
>
> @Unfinished(owners="xyz",
>                   value="Method scope")
>
> public void foo()

---

Can `@Documented` annotation resolve this problem?

or

Do I need to write a compile-time annotation processor for a new custom annotation instead of using meta annotation(`@Documented`)?

Comment: "Do I need to write a compile-time annotation processor", — basically yes, except in your case it is called "doclet".